# SQL Server query issues with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I have to write a query regarding the statement below:

> List all directors who directed 50 movies or more, in descending order of the number of movies they directed. Return the directors' names and the number of movies each of them directed.

I have written multiple variations but I keep getting errors.

It involves joins. The tables involved are:

- `Directors` (directorID, firstname, lastname),
- `Movie_Directors` (directorID, movieID).

What I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    firstname, lastname,
    COUNT(movie_directors.directorID)
FROM 
    dbo.movie_directors
INNER JOIN 
    directors ON directors.directorID = movie_directors.directorID
GROUP BY
    firstname, lastname
HAVING 
    COUNT(movie_directors.directorID) >= 50
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Um, as the error message tells you, the column isn't in your group by clause. Basically, because you don't have one. Without the group by, you can't use the having clause.

Comment: Is it `MS SQL` per your title or `MySQL` per your tag? They're totally different systems with significantly different syntax at times.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow. Adding text like "VERY IMPORTANT" to your title won't get you extra attention because everyone's question is important to them. But it will tick some people off, and you will see fewer people look at your question, especially when it's something fairly trivial and easy.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's MS SQL

Comment: In that case, please correct your tag.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thank you for the heads up! Just joined!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a `GROUP BY`, any column not in an aggregate function MUST be in the `GROUP BY` clause [MSDN - Group By (Transact SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql).

The reasoning is this: a `GROUP` by smashes records by the unique sets of values of each column in the group by, so any column not in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause would be outside of the purpose of a group by.

So by forcing an aggregate function for the columns, we guarantee the select statement is purposeful in its results...which should be how you code anyways.

Also, `COUNT()` ignores `NULL` values anyways and your `ON` predicate will only return on matches between the two tables on the director_ID. `INNER JOIN` will not return null results.

So use use a `COUNT(<group by colum>)` in your select statement.
Lastly, your `HAVING` clause is another predicate and can only be used with a `GROUP BY`. 
[MSDN - HAVING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql)

Comment: Note you can use a `COUNT(*)` in your select statement,  but i was hoping to avoid confusion as COUNT(*) is a row-set counter in TSQL and is not the same as SELECT *